# .Net Core 2.1 Identity - reference errors

Tags: c#, identity, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-mac

Environment:

- Visual Studio for Mac community
- .Net Core 2.1 (2.1.301 & 2.1.504 installed)

I'm trying to create a .net core MVC app using Identity.  Using CLI I create my project with

```
dotnet new mvc -o myproject --auth Individual
```

I'm trying to scaffold my project using code generator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project

I run the following:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

and I get the following error:  **error: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language. Install/reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.2.0 directly to project myproject to resolve this issue.**

I tried installing that specific version

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language --version 2.2.0
```

After running dotnet restore I get several other errors:
**Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.2.0 was resolved.**

Along with another version conflict errors for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.2.0

Any suggestions on how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue I fixed it by using an earlier version of CodeGeneration

`dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design --version 2.1.7`